# How do I get TypeScript typechecking only for specific objects in an otherwise non-TS file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using JSDoc to define and use types. I have a types.d.ts file and am importing and using it like so:

```
/** @typedef { import("./types").Requests } Requests */

/** @type Requests */
const theReq = {
    notes: 12,  // this is typed as string and errors as expected
}
```

When I add `// @ts-check` to the top of the file, the `notes:` entry redlines, which I want.

Since it's a legacy project tho, parts of the rest of the file redline as well, which I don't want.

But if I leave off `// @ts-check`, it will still give intellisense suggestions, but doesn't redline.

How do I set up TypeScript granularity so that it will check and redline ***only*** the objects that are JSDoc typed?

Comment: Don't think you can. It's not like ESLint where we'd have `// @ts-check-start` and `// @ts-check-end`

Comment: @kelly that's what I thought but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options at the moment for this kind of thing

- `// @ts-nocheck` or `// @ts-check` to disable / enable type checking for a file
- `// @ts-expect-error` to disable type checking for one line